# alpha diversity indices using estimateR (vegan package) in R

Tags: r, vegan

I am using estimateR function in the vegan package in R for estimating various chao diversity estimates. However it returns 0 for all samples in se.chao1 and NaN for S.ace and se.ace. Also the S.obs and S.chao1 columns have same values.

The dataset is a absolute abundance matrix with numbers varying from 0 to a high value.

```
dataset <- c(
0, 0, 57550, 0, 0, 2649956, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 402418, 0, 292221, 0, 0, 11408954,
879793, 7046, 91526835, 882521, 0, 0, 12258322, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 720097, 0, 14781762, 0, 29370, 4319441, 462408, 0, 4808129, 0, 48946, 0,
261708, 0, 13543665, 0, 425312, 3482180, 614839, 0, 7622227, 0, 0, 1167266, 0,
0, 32642704, 0, 20674, 0, 0, 0, 16958655, 0, 0, 8530916, 0
)
dataset <- matrix(dataset, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(dataset) <- c(
"Rothia", "Bifidobacterium", "Scardovia",
"Adlercreutzia", "Collinsella", "Eggerthella"
)

chao <- vegan::estimateR(dataset)
```

I found it weird getting 0 and NaN, would you be able to help me with this? Is this right or an error?
And if right how to interpret it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please add some example data and the code you've been using so far? Otherwise, it's hard to help you fixing the problem.

Comment: Sure, the code I used is chao <- estimateR(dataset). A small part of my dataset is like this: Rothia Bifidobacterium Scardovia Adlercreutzia Collinsella Eggerthella
0 0 57550 0 0 2649956
0 0 0 0 0 402418
0 292221 0 0 11408954 879793
7046 91526835 882521 0 0 12258322
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 720097
0 14781762 0 29370 4319441 462408
0 4808129 0 48946 0 1261708
0 13543665 0 425312 3482180 614839
0 7622227 0 0 1167266 0
0 32642704 0 20674 0 0
0 16958655 0 0 8530916 0

Comment: Please, add data in a way people can parse it into R. See above...

Comment: Rothia Bifidobacterium Scardovia Adlercreutzia Collinsella Eggerthella
0 0 57550 0 0 2649956
0 0 0 0 0 402418
0 292221 0 0 11408954 879793
7046 91526835 882521 0 0 12258322
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 720097
0 14781762 0 29370 4319441 462408
0 4808129 0 48946 0 1261708
0 13543665 0 425312 3482180 614839
0 7622227 0 0 1167266 0
0 32642704 0 20674 0 0
0 16958655 0 0 8530916 0
My apologies, is that better? Because I cant find any way to attach a file

Comment: Sorry, my edits got lost. This is what I meant by adding the data:
```
dataset <- c(
  0, 0, 57550, 0, 0, 2649956, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 402418, 0, 292221, 0, 0, 11408954,
  879793, 7046, 91526835, 882521, 0, 0, 12258322, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 720097, 0, 14781762, 0, 29370, 4319441, 462408, 0, 4808129, 0, 48946, 0,
  1261708, 0, 13543665, 0, 425312, 3482180, 614839, 0, 7622227, 0, 0, 1167266,
  0, 0, 32642704, 0, 20674, 0, 0, 0, 16958655, 0, 0, 8530916, 0
)
```

Comment: dataset <- matrix(dataset, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(dataset) <- c("Rothia", "Bifidobacterium", "Scardovia", "Adlercreutzia", "Collinsella", "Eggerthella")

Comment: Okay I understand, but you wouldn't want me to give this to you now right, sorry I mean you already made it? Do you need the complete dataset?  Also I would like to mention that these could be wrong as this was genera level but I tried species level as well and still the same!

Comment: Hi, sorry but I was very curious and I tried making a new dataset with sqrt values of the original one. (thinking that these values are too big which might be creating the issue). A single sqrt did not work and so I took sqrt of the sqrt values and the estimateR of that dataset. It worked somehow! Not completely, still got some NaN but do you think large values don't work well with Chao or estimateR?

Comment: Now other uses can easily replicate your problem, I've also added the vegan tag. I hope someone who knows about vegan will help you with your problem. I have never used this package myself, so I can't be of any help. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the help page may be a good idea if all other fails. First it gives you the equations where the extrapolation is based on rare species, and then it expands the concept of rarity:

> S_rare is the number of rare species, S_abund is the number of abundant
> species, with an arbitrary threshold of abundance 10 for rare
> species, and N_rare is the number of individuals in rare species

The rarest species in your data set has count 7046 which is well above the threshold of 10. If you have observed at least 7000 individuals of rarest species, the method assumes there are no rare species, you have observed all species and there is no more to find. There is nothing to estimate for `estimateR` and therefore the estimates also are 0 or 0/0 (NaN).

The method is unsuitable for your data, and you should not use it. Reading the original papers (referred in the help page) will give more information to the same effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I may be wrong here but then this would be a common issue right? Basically this is metaphlan2 output which I converted to absolute abundance by multiplying the relative abundance value by the number of reads in each sample. If this gives such a high value would this make it a common issue? As it is necessary that once converts the relative abundance to absolute right?

Comment: You should do this kind of calculations with raw data: it is a different thing to have one read than 7000 fake-reads (6999 of which you didn't have). If you do manipulations like this, do them first on data and only after that multiply to fictitious numbers.

Comment: Sorry but that means you are saying I should use the relative abundance count rather than the absolute abundance counts from metadata for the analyses?

Comment: No I didn't say so. I said you should use *observed* counts. The `estimateR` function is only suitable for observed counts as it is based on idea of using *rare* cases, and rarity is only meaningful for observations (you have *seen* something less than ten times is rare). However, it may be that your data are such that `estimateR` is not a method for them.